# How to update item count from cartscreen to and back to restaurant detail screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-listview

I am working on a food delivery app where users click on add items from restaurantDetail screen and add items to the cart. In a cart screen when a user makes changes in a specific item count. I wants update same item count in each item on a restaurantDetail screen ?

I am passing the entire cart list on a callback from a cartlist and getting the same list on a restaurantDetail screen. How can I update item count in it ?

On a callback I am returning this Function with a total and callbackFromCart as a parameter.

```
final Function(double, List<CartModel>) callbackFromCart;
```

and on a RestaturantDetailScreen i am getting the same on a below function:

```
onCartBackPress(totalPriceFromCart, List<CartModel> _listFromCartItem) {
print("LIST FROM CART :${_listFromCartItem}");
for (var item in _listFromCartItem) {
  for (var mainrestaurantItem in _itemList) {
    if (mainrestaurantItem.id == item.restaurantItemId) {
      mainrestaurantItem.totalQty = item.totalQty;
      updatedItemCount = mainrestaurantItem.totalQty;
      print("UPDATED ITEM COUNT : $updatedItemCount");
    }
  }
}
setState(() {
  _totalPrice = totalPriceFromCart;
});
print(_itemList);
if (_listFromCartItem.isEmpty == true) {
  getRestaurantDetail();
}
```

}

Comment: You should consider implementing app state management  widgets like ``provider``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _RestaurantState extends State<RestaurantPage> {
  
  StreamController<List<YourItemModel> itemsController = StreamController<List<YourItemModel>>();
  List<YoutItemModel> itemsList = [];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .....
      
      StreamBuilder<List<YourItemModel>(
      stream: itemsController.stream,
      builder: (con, data){
       //check for loading or empty data here
       //else return listview
       return ListView.builder(
        ......
       );
      }
      
      ),
      
    .....
      
      override
      void dispose(){
      itemsController.close();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }
  
  void gotoCartPage() async {
    
    List<YourItemModel> newList = await Navigator.push(
    context, builder: (c)=> CartPage(items: itemsList));
    
    if(newList != null){
      itemsList.clear();
      itemsList.addAll(newList);
      itemsController.sink.add(itemsList);
    }
  }
  
}

  // In CartPage
  
  class CartPage extends StatefulWidget{
    
    final List<YourItemModel> list;
    CartPage({Key k, required this.list}) : super(key:k);
    
    @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState(list);
    
  }
  
  class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
    _CartPageState(this.modifiedList);
    
    List<YourItemModel> modifiedList;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        Navigator.of(context).pop(modifiedList);
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
       //Increase or decrease your items from itemsList in CartPage
       //and return modified list to the parent/restaurant screen
      .....
      ),
     );
  }
 }
```